# how to do partial search and replace in a file in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I know how to do search and replace for the whole file. Can it also be done partially?

I sometimes need this feature because I use a wrong variable for a method sometimes and I want to correct my mistake without changing the variable name globally.

For example, I want to replace the word "colour" with "color" only for lines from 100 to 200. Can you do that in sublime text?

Or, say I want to only search and replace the bottom half of the file.
How can I do that?

Is there a way to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to select the part of the text you want to change before pressing "Ctrl + H".
 Then all you'll do will effect what you've selected, even if you choose "Replace all"